# Switch div content on the fly, php didn't do it for me

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

im looking for a good way to switch out content on the fly, i tried with a php switch, it worked but, the problem was that when the switch was activated, the page was reloaded back to the top, instead of staying where the content switched.

what i want to achieve as a gallery where a can switch out a group images with some buttons.

example i want a button that switches this group:

```
<div class="galleryimg img1">
</div>
<div class="galleryimg img2">
</div>
<div class="galleryimg img3">
</div>
<div class="galleryimg img4">
</div>
```

with another group like this:

```
<div class="galleryimg img5">
</div>
<div class="galleryimg img6">
</div>
<div class="galleryimg img7">
</div>
<div class="galleryimg img8">
</div>
```

Is i said i achieved it with php, but the page reloaded back to the top, so that wasn't and option.

heres the php i used, just retyped it fast again didn't check it for typos:

```
<a href="index.php?side=forside">forside</a><a href="index.php?side=side2">side2</a>

<?php
    $side=$_GET['side'];

    if(empty($side)){
        $side='forside';
    }else{
        $side=$side;
    }
?>

<?php
    switch($side){
        case 'forside':
        include('php/forside.php');
        break;

        case 'side2':
        include('php/side2.php');
        break;

        default:
        include('php/forside.php');
        break;
    }
?>
```

any other good suggestions.

Thanks ;)

Comment: hint: use javascript.

Comment: add php code that you use

Answer (score 0):

Your [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement is not correct. Try:

```
switch($side){
    case 'forside':// Colon instead of semicolon
    include('incs/forside.php');
    break;

    case 'side2':// Colon instead of semicolon
    include('incs/side2.php');
    break;// Break to avoid executing `default` part

    default:// Colon instead of semicolon
    include('incs/forside.php');
    break;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Print everything, hide the content you don't want to show using jquery or javascript and when the user clicks the link, switch content out. This can serve you as a sketch:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#side2").hide(); // Hide side2 to start off

    $("#foreside_c").click(function (ev) {// Click on link, hide one show other.
        ev.preventDefault();
        $("#side2").hide();
        $("#foreside").show();
    });

    $("#side2_c").click(function (ev) {// Click on link, hide one show other.
        ev.preventDefault();
        $("#foreside").hide();
        $("#side2").show();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzrz1hcu/6/)

Comment: Well the php did what it was suppose to, the problem is that the content i want to replace is 4x viewport height down the page, so when the php replaces the content it reloads the page, and then the user has to scroll back down.

Comment: @ThomasRavnholt ok, I've updated the answer, you can take it as an example and modify it if you like.

Comment: ill give it a look ;)
i have very limited jquery and javascript knowledge ;)

Comment: nope can't do it ;) i guess ill have to study some javascript and jquery soon. ;)

Comment: @ThomasRavnholt No worries, hope it helped to give you an idea.

Comment: Well its just a hobby, i started programmering web 3-4 months ago. but i guess im at the point now where ill have to study some javascript. any tips for where to begin ? :)

Comment: @ThomasRavnholt sure, check `Javascript: the good parts` if you want to learn javascript, highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an ajax call. Send a variable to your php script. Then get the response back, and use jquery to swap the data. Quick example of ajax to php. So have the php echo out the html block.

```
$.ajax({
    "url": "./path-to-php.php",
    "type": "GET",
    "dataType": "html",
    "data": {"side": "forside"},
    success: function(data){
        $("#forside").html(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jquery to do this?
only change the attr src

I did this for one element, if click over a picture.
You can copy for all your div and put a event over a button

```
$(document).on("click", "#imgTest", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      $(this).attr("src","http://i639.photobucket.com/albums/uu112/mich36/Tropical-Breeze.jpg");

    });
```

see the fidlle http://jsfiddle.net/87bmncex/